# How can I send an email with signature and image without the direct path?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am looking to send an email containing a range of an Excel document with the sender's default signature (which contains an image).

I am using what seems to be the go to method, shown below. Originally, I could not get the email to appear without changing the .htm file's image src to link directly to the relevant image. This worked, but I need a solution that doesn't require the direct path.

At work, our computers will update the signature folder on startup and it overwrites any changes I make to it. I have to make this program adaptable to any work computer, so I can't specifically change each img src path.

Is there a method to allow access to the full signature without the direct path, or any other workaround?

The .htm file represents the signature and references an image within it's source. It kind of looks like `<img border=0 width=240 height=148 src="MYCOMPANY%20Signature_files/image001.png" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_1"></span><![endif]></span></a><span style='font-size:8.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif; color:#A1A0A4'>`.

I was able to change the `src =`  directly to the path of the image on my computer, but because that gets overwritten I can't use that as a solution.

```vb
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
a = customerContact
b = salesExec
Dim Ebody As String
Ebody = "placeholder"
Ebody = Cells(3, 2) & "<br>" _
  & "<br>" _
  & "Dear, " & customerFirstName & "<br>" _
  & "<br>" _
  & Cells(7, 2) & "<br>" _
  & "<br>" _
  & Cells(9, 2) & "<br>" _
  & "<br>" _
  & Cells(11, 2) & "<br>" _
  & "<br>" _
  & Cells(13, 2)
Signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
If Dir(Signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    Signature = Signature & Dir$(Signature & "*.htm")
Else:
    Signature = ""
End If
        
Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(Signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
        
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = customerContact
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = salesExec
    .Subject = "Welcome"
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    'or if you dont want it to auto send.....change  .send  to .display
    .HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" _
      & Ebody _
      & "<br>" _
      & "<br>" & Signature
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
 
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
 
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: *overwrite any changes I make to it* <-- what changes are you making to it / why is this relevant? *I could not get the email to appear without changing the .htm file's image src* <-- Your code does not appear to be changing the .htm file at all.     Can you clarify your problem statement?

Comment: The .htm file represents the signature and references an image within it's source. It kind of looks like `<img
border=0 width=240 height=148 src="MYCOMPANY%20Signature_files/image001.png" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_1"></span><![endif]></span></a><span
style='font-size:8.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
color:#A1A0A4'>`. I was able to change the `src = ` directly to the path of the image on my computer, but because that gets overwritten I can't use that as a solution.

Comment: OK, so let's see if I understand this correctly (and if I do, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38459795/edit) your question to clarify this point): You altered the HTML file so that the VBA program will work. You would like a solution which does not require you to alter the HTML file in advance?

Comment: To add, unless I edit the `src = `, then the image does not appear in emails at all. I get a blank image with an 'x', but I do get the text of the signature. I need a way to get the entire signature with image, without using the code above because it relies on `img src` having a direct path to the image used in the signature, and changing that is beyond my power.

Comment: OK excellent, now put all that great detail in the question body so that everyone can see it more readily :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, Yes essentially. Sorry posted the new info before you replied.

Comment: So the `src` attribute *was* a relative path and you changed it to an *absolute* path? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the `src ` was a relative path, but I read from several solutions that the workaround was to change it to a direct path. This worked for me, but unfortunately I can't apply it to the application.

Comment: One possible solution would be to use an HTML/DOM parser to manipulate the `.htm` file at run-time, changing the `src` attribute from relative to absolute path. Let me see if I can whip something up to that effect.

Comment: @DavidZemens, thank you greatly for your help. I was thinking that might be a solution, but is something like that possible in VBA? I'm genuinely not aware.

Comment: Yep, it should be possible I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, I kind of worked out something below. It works, but relies on me knowing the user's path beforehand. It will probably be sufficient for my needs, but anything better would be appreciated. Just letting you know, thanks.

Comment: Nice work -- I got sidetracked for a moment but I'll have something else for you shortly.

Comment: OK so getting the HTM file is more difficult than I thought (I have had some issues with these Microsoft files in the past) -- ultimately what you're trying to do is simply insert the user's default signature, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I thought this should be possible to parse the HTML and manipulate it at run-time, but that gave me a lot more trouble than I anticipated, but if I understand correctly, you just need to insert the signature by default, and I think what you're doing is causing a problem because you're manipulating the `.HTMLBody` before Outlook would be able to do this.  Outlook will add the user's default signature if a `MailItem.Display` or `MailItem.GetInspector` is called *before* the `HTMLBody` is edited.

Here's a simple example:

```
Sub foo()
Dim Signature$
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

olMail.GetInspector
Signature = olMail.HTMLBody
olMail.HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>blah blah blah" _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<br>" & Signature

olMail.display  '## Verify you can see the signature

End Sub
```

Try this. The idea is to call on the `.GetInspector` (which should insert the signature correctly), then capture the `Signature = .HTMLBody` (to append to the end of email later), add your custom HTML, and then append the `Signature`.

```
With OutMail
        .GetInspector ' ## This inserts default signature
        Signature = .HTMLBody ' ## Capture the signature HTML
        .To = customerContact
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = salesExec
        .Subject = "Welcome"
         ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
         ' display the e-mail message.
        'or if you dont want it to auto send.....change  .send  to .display
        .HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" _
        & Ebody _
        & "<br>" _
        & Signature
        .display
End With
```

How it works:

> Outlook adds the signature to the new unmodified messages (you should not modify the body prior to that) when you call `MailItem.Display` (which causes the message to be displayed on the screen) or when you access the `MailItem.GetInspector` property

Full code can omit some of your previous dealings with `Signature` and FSO, etc.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
a = customerContact
b = salesExec
Dim Ebody As String
Ebody = "placeholder"
Ebody = Cells(3, 2) & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& "Dear, " & customerFirstName & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& Cells(7, 2) & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& Cells(9, 2) & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& Cells(11, 2) & "<br>" _
& "<br>" _
& Cells(13, 2)

'!---- NO LONGER NEEDED ----!>
'Signature = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
'If Dir(Signature, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
'    Signature = Signature & Dir$(Signature & "*.htm")
'Else:
'    Signature = ""
'End If

' Signature = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(Signature).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
'<!-------------------------!>

With OutMail
        .GetInspector ' ## This inserts default signature
        Signature = .HTMLBody ' ## Capture the signature HTML
        .To = customerContact
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = salesExec
        .Subject = "Welcome"
         ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
         ' display the e-mail message.
        'or if you dont want it to auto send.....change  .send  to .display
        .HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" _
        & Ebody _
        & "<br>" _
        & Signature
        .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you David! This works perfectly. Only difference is client has to approve access to their contacts, but that's fine because the application is going to require permissions regardless.

Comment: You could probably use `.Display` instead of `GetInspector` that may not require approval in this case but it does display/show the email before it's fully populated, so that may not be desireable. Cheers, and if this has solved the problem do consider accepting the answer or upvoting it :)

Comment: If Display works, then it actually solves both my problems, because in some instances I want to batch send and other times I need the clients to preview what they are sending. So it works either way. Also, I'd love to upvote but I still need more points. I did approve though. Edit: Display did work!

Comment: Keep in mind that as of 2017-ish, GetInspector trick no longer works - only Display does.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out one solution that seems alright. Instead of editing the .htm file, I extract the image from the .htm path and tack it on to the .HTML body.

You can move the signature and image around to your needs, I just wanted to make sure it worked first.

In essence, the modification only applies to the `With OutMail` section of the code, and it looks like this (but I removed company relevant stuff):

```
With OutMail
            .To = customerContact
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = salesExec
            .Subject = "Welcome"
             ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
             ' display the e-mail message.
            'or if you dont want it to auto send.....change  .send  to .display
            .HTMLBody = "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" _
            & Ebody _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<img src='c:\Users\<YOUR USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\<SIGNATURE FILES FOLDER>\image001.png'>" _
            & "<br>" & Signature
            .display
    End With
```